# File Transfer w/ python

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to make a program that will:
Copy & Paste a Directory and place it, and it's contents into a new location. I do not think my code is right for this, I think it is simple just moving the file to a totally different location

```
import os
import shutil
login = os.getlogin()

SOURCE_FILE_DEKSTOP =  '/Users/%s/Desktop' % (login)
DST_FILE_WD = 'Users/%s/WorkDocs' % (login)

shutil.move(SOURCE_FILE_DEKSTOP, DST_FILE_WD)
```

I am getting this error as well

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/gomcrai/pythings/fileTransfer.py", line 8, in <module>
    shutil.move(SOURCE_FILE_DEKSTOP, DST_FILE_WD)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib    /python2.7/shutil.py", line 300, in move
rmtree(src)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 256, in rmtree
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 254, in rmtree
os.rmdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/gomcrai/Desktop'
```

Comment: So...do you have permission to move that file?

Comment: I am a Domain Admin, and the account im doing this on is set to local admin, so I should have the ability to do this. OS = Mac, incase anyone needed to know

Answer (score 1):

If you genuinely want to copy, rather than move, then [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) is a better bet. `move` will, well, move the entry, deleting the original.

You're getting an error because Macs have access control lists on the folders that it thinks should always be there, and `Desktop` is one of those, since it's used to store all the files visible on your desktop. Since `shutil.move` is trying to delete that, it's meeting the ACL and being denied.

`ls -ale /Users/gomcrai/Desktop` should show you the ACL, displaying something like: `0: group:everyone deny delete`

If you'd like to *cut* and paste rather than *copy* and paste the directory, you could either use `os.listdir` or `os.walk` and find files and folders inside `Desktop/` and move all of those, or use `shutil.copytree` on `Desktop` and then remove everything inside `Desktop` while leaving that folder alone.

Comment: I definitely want to copy being we have infosec policies here where we have to retain the info on the orginal device for 2 weeks minimum.  Thank you very much !

Comment: I also want it to overwrite the Destination Folder if there is one already in there I re adjusted my code to create a folder inside my destination but if it already exists I want it to just overwrite it @Simon Fraser